# Linq to Entities - Subquery in the where statement

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

This must be simple, but I've been searching for 2 hours, and can't find an answer. How do I write this in Linq to Entities:

```
SELECT Reg4, Reg5, Reg6
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE Reg1 = 15
AND Reg2 = ( SELECT MAX(Reg2) FROM dbo.Table2 WHERE Reg1 = 15);
```

Is it possible to do it both in query expressions and method based syntaxes? 
Tks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var r1 = 15;
var q = from t in Context.Table1
        where t.Reg1 == r1 && 
              t.Reg2 == Context.Table2
                               .Where(t2 => t2.Reg1 == r1)
                               .Max(t2 => t2.Reg2)
        select t;
```

Easier still if you have a navigation/association from Table1 to Table2. But you didn't show that, so neither will I....

Comment: Yes, there is an association between Table1 and Table2, where Table1.Reg1 = Table2.Reg2. Thank you for your time

Comment: I keep getting Delegate 'System.Func<EntityFrameDemo.Table1,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments at the where clause!

Comment: This works in 2021 in EF6 ... After 4-5 years using EF, It is nice to know that i can reference the dbContext inside the 'Where()' clause.