# how to implement select statement as a column in Linq to entity or Method-Based query?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

i want to use subquery in a column in **Linq to Entity** or **Method-Based** query

for example, something like this in sql server:

```
select (select a1 from a as A where A.b_ID = B.ID), b1
from b as B
```

is there any way in linq to entity or method-based query syntax?

Comment: How do you know that the subquery returns only one value?

Comment: assuming that both table have one to one relationship and for any one record from table a there is one record from table b

Comment: You should express that in the EF mapping and use a navigation property.

Comment: yes i know, but i want to know that, is there any way to use subquery as column in linq or method-based without mapping? 
for example can be used subquery in the where statement
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694212/)